# Where are Databricks "create table using" options documented

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using Databricks "CREATE TABLE USING" functionality documented [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html) using something like the following.

```
create table value_set.value_set_meta 
using csv 
options ( 
  header = "true", 
  delimiter = ",", 
  inferSchema = "false", 
  path = "/FileStore/tables/prod/global/value_set_meta" 
)
```

I'd like to know if there is an option to trim white spaces from all columns (and/or for specific columns).  Where are the options that are allowed here listed and documented?

Answer (score 1):

I bet the options are

```
ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace = "true",
ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace = "true",
```

because the other options look so similar to those documented in the [pyspark csv reader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv). Not sure if trimming spaces from specific columns is possible though.